# Javascript : "[classname] is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, mootools, undefined

I was looking for an image cropping plugin when i found this one : [Lasso.Crop](http://www.nwhite.net/2009/02/25/lassocrop-preview). I wanted to try code example, but by using code example provided and the same files they use i had never been able to make it work locally, and i always having an error "Lasso is not defined" here :

```
new Lasso.Crop('bee',{
    ratio : false,
    preset : [235,140,505,340],
    min : [50,50],
    handleSize : 8,
    opacity : .6,
    color : '#7389AE',
    border : '/images/crop.gif',
    onResize : updateCoords
});
```

I never managed to make it work.
A few hours ago i tried another plugin : [UvumiTools Crop](http://uvumitools.com/crop.html) and a similar issue appears. The demo works perfectly on their site, but the demo archive i downloaded on their site doesn't work locally. Here again the error a very similar to the previous one : "uvumiCropper is not defined" (uvumiCropper is a class defined in the plugin).

I don't understand why i keep getting "[...] is not defined" errors whereas the code actually defines a such class or function is a previously imported javascript file.

Maybe i am doing something wrong, i don't know, but i already lost hours on this, so every advice is welcomed.

The demo archive for UvumiTools Cropper is downloadable on this [page](http://uvumitools.com/crop.html).

Thanks

Comment: please provide your code.

Comment: Did you load the Lasso `.js` files?

Comment: Of course i did. I also tried on a copy of the page on which the demo is hosted.

Answer (score 4):

there are two files you need to load, in order, after mootools:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Lasso.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Lasso.Crop.js"></script>
```

Lasso will export the Lasso constructor function to global object.
Lasso.Crop will add `Crop` property to the Lasso object. It will try to `Extend` the base `Lasso` Class. You cannot just load Lasso.Crop.js and hope that it works

Keep in mind this is 4 years old, written for MooTools 1.2 and may not work with 1.4.5 unless you use -compat build. Nathan White has not done any MooTools work for about 3 years (that I know of).

Comment: I did exactly what they say on the site. I even tried to copy the page where the demo is on the site, but this didn't work neither. I tried to get Js files in local or access the files on the demo server, i still get the same error.

Comment: @dimitar-christoff : What you say is exactly what i did, i'm loading Mootools, then Lasso, then Lasso.Crop and, when i use Lasso.Crop after this i get the error. I'm using the mootool version he's using on his demo page.

Comment: then look at your console and make sure the scripts are loaded. `console.log(window.Lasso)`, make sure it's there. make sure there are no 404s. make sure MooTools has finished loading. His version of mootools should NOT be used.